# C language how to call a member of multi-dimensional array in corresponding to a structure

Tags: c

I have a problem with how to call a member of a structure. For example, there is a struct

```
typedef struct FAVORITE_TBL_S
{
    UI32_T apple;
    UI32_T banana;
    UI16_T puzzle;
    UI16_T car;
}FAVORITE_TBL_T;
```

And in the function, I have created a multi-dimensional array about this struct.

```
FUNCTION_NO_T
call_myFavoriteTbl(
    const UI32_T unit,
    const UI32_T value)
{
    FUNCTION_NO_T ret = FUNCTION_E_GOOD;
    UI8_T num_of_list = 4;
    UI32_T i = 0;
    FAVORITE_TBL_T *ptr_fav = NULL;
    
    ptr_fav = priviate_alloc(sizeof(FAVORITE_TBL_T ) * num_of_list );
    priviate_memset(ptr_fav, 0, sizeof(FAVORITE_TBL_T ) * num_of_list );

    /* In this function, if I want to use member in the multi-dim array */
    for (i = 0, i < value, i++)
    {
        if (BRAND_PINKLADY == ptr_fav[i]->apple)
        {
            printf("I love it!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("I don't want to eat.");
        }

        if (BRAND_COSTAPICA == ptr_fav[i].banana)
        {
            printf("I love it!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("I don't want to eat.");
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

So why ptr_fav[i]->apple is wrong and ptr_fav[i].banana is right?

Comment: `ptr_fav` is an array of those structs. `ptr_fav[i]` gives one of the structs, not a pointer. So need `.` rather than `->` to access the fields.

Comment: Why are you comparing the array elements to different values when you never filled in the array with data?

Comment: This isn't a multidiemensional array. It's a 1D array of structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `ptr_fav` is an array of `FAVORITE_TBL_T` values, `ptr_fav[i]` is a  `FAVORITE_TBL_T` value. It is *not* a pointer to `FAVORITE_TBL_T`.

As such, the `.` notation is correct.

Now, because `ptr_fav[i]` is equivalent to `*(ptr + i)`, you might write: `(ptr_fav + i)->apple`, though I'm not sure *why* you'd want to do that.

The `->` operator is used to access a field on a *pointer* to a structure.

Answer (score 0):

ptr_fav[i] has already dereferenced it and now you have structure value not pointer. If you want to use -> you should try (ptr_fav + i)->apple.